# How to display a googlemaps marker containing data from all documents in a firestore collection with the same geopoint

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

I'm designing a webpage that will be able to retrieve a marker field[geopoint] that is similar for all documents in the collection from firestore and displays all the different documents' fields in an infowindow.
However, on retrieving the marker, I can only see one marker and its fields and not the rest of the other documents' fields.
**Screenshots of the collection**:
[document1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yByM9.png)   [document2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpqar.png)   [document3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsPzX.png)

[On clicking the marker, only one document is being displayed on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQp30.png)

Here's the code:

```
<?php

include_once 'header.php';

?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<script>

   firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
   });

   const db = firebase.firestore();
   db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});




    var map;
    var marker;
    var infowindow;
    var green_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png' ;
    var purple_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png' ;




    function initMap() {

        var options = {
            zoom: 8,
            center:  {lat: 1.2921, lng: 36.8219}
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);


        function addMarker(coords, icon, content, animation){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:  coords,

                map: map,
                icon: icon,

                animation: animation
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: content

            });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }



        db.collection('Nairobi').get().then((snapshot) => {

            // var data = snapshot.data();
            snapshot.docs.forEach(function(child){
                var name_loc = child.id;
                var loc = child.data().marker;
                var forward = child.data().ForwardPower;
                var reflected = child.data().ReflectedPower;

                var ups = child.data().UPSError;
                var upsDesc = child.data().UPSDesc;
                var trans = child.data().TransmitterError;
                var transDesc = child.data().TransDesc;


                    addMarker(
                        {lat: loc.latitude, lng: loc.longitude },
                        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png', '' +
                        `<h1> ${name_loc}</h1>` + "<br/>"
                        +  `<h2> Forward Power: ${forward} </h2>` 
                        + "<br/>" + `<h2> Reflected Power: ${reflected} </h2>`
                        + "<br/>" + `<h2> UPS Error: ${ups} </h2>`
                        + "<br/>" + `<h2> TransmitterError: ${trans} </h2>`

                    );

                console.log(child.id, child.data());
            });

   })
   }






</script>


<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en&key=[API KEY]&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

On the web console, there is no error and I get back arrays of the documents as shown below: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh1FE.png)

Comment: Do you get an error in the Web console?

Comment: No i dont, I get back all the three documents and their fields as an array

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works. Can you update your question with your entire code, including the way you initialize the Google map.

Comment: I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to Renaud's answer, this is indeed intended behaviour, by default Google Maps API displays only top marker.
To achieve desirable behaviour you can use [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) library, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You have **exactly the same values** of `markers` for the three Firestore documents! So the markers are stacked on your map and you only see one.

Just change the values and you will see the three different markers since your code works.

---

Also note that you could do:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(child){...})
```

instead of

```
snapshot.docs.forEach(function(child){...})
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#for-each

Comment: Okay, so what can I do so that I can display all that data in one infowindow since the have the same marker value?